# How do I sort an array in JavaScript, ensuring one element goes to the top?

Tags: javascript, sorting

I have an array of URLs, and I want the current URL to be the top most member, and the rest in alphabetical order. The `links` array starts off in alphabetical order ascending.

The `links` array looks like this...

```
var links = [
    'http://example.com',
    'http://example.net',
    'http://stackoverflow.com'
];
```

But my current URL may be `http://stackoverflow.com/questions`. This should match the 2nd member above.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why not this simple approach?

1. Remove the current URL from the array e.g. `Array.splice(Array.indexOf(url), 1)`
2. Sort the array alphabetically
3. Use `Array.unshift()` to prepend the current URL

Less checks, only a simple splice and unshift.

**Update**

If you need to match the current domain.

1. Sort the array using your own compare function
2. In case the current item A matches the url, return -1 to make it bubble up
3. In case item B matches, return 0 to make it stay
4. In case neither A or B, or both A and B match the url, just return the normal comparision to sort them

This is untested, but in theory it should work.

Comment: Sorry, I should mention that the URL is not the exact URL, just a list of domains. Will edit. Also, you can see I am accessing the `href` property of each link in the array, so an `indexOf()` won't suffice unfortunately. Thanks for your answer :)

Comment: Updated with a `.sort(function(){...})` approach.

Answer (score 3):

Whilst waiting for an answer, I came up with this...

```
var matchRegex = new RegExp('^' + RegExp.escape('http://' + window.location.hostname));

var newLinks = [];

for (var i = 0, linksLength = links.length; i < linksLength; i++) {

      if (links[i].href.match(matchRegex)) {
          newLinks.push(links[i]);
          links.splice(i, 1);
          break;
      };

};

newLinks = newLinks.concat(links);
```

Seems to work nicely.

Comment: @Marcel Korpel They start off in alphabetical order though, and appear to be remain that way after this code.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use .unshift()?

```
links.sort(); //first sort alphabetically
links.unshift(thisURL); //then add the current URL to the top
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to include some relevant information. See my edit.